# Примеры из книги "Мастерская CSS. Профессиональное применение Web-стандартов."

Tags: css

В данный момент читаю данную книгу, в которой содержиться большое количество примеров (чаще всего это готовые изображения), которые автор рекомендует скачать с сайта friendsofed.com. Сайт недоступен, а продолжительный поиск результатов не дал. Может у кого-то есть, или кто-то знает где достать таковые. Книга основана на примерах и без них изученные данной книги бессмысленно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тынц](http://www.cssmastery.com/)
Удивляют меня простейшие вопросы по поиску в гугле.

Comment: Антон, бесконечное спасибо!